# What does this « le »do?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

I’m reading this line:

> Comme les Français, nous *le* savons, respectent le passé, l'âge et la
> tradition…

May I ask what does the “*le*” in *“nous le savons”* mean? And how come there is a “respectent” after it? There’s not a third person plural as the subject…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Le" is simply a pronoun ([pronouns](https://www.espacefrancais.com/les-pronoms/)); what it is used in replacement of is something that comes (essentially) after (the unit being replaced  comes before the pronoun but occasionally  after); that unit is "les Français … respectent le passé, l'âge et la tradition ".

"Respectent" has "les Français" for subject; "nous le savons" is what you call "[une incise"](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/incise).

- Comme les Français respectent le passé, l'âge et la tradition, nous le savons,… (*equivalent formulation*)
- Elle ne sait pas ça ; je te **le** rappelle, ne **l**'oublie pas. (*before; unit being replaced by "le" and "l": "elle ne sait pas ça"*)
- De la façon dont elle le conçoit, le problème n'est pas abordable. (*after; "le" replaces "problème"*)

Comment: While LPH is absolutely right, in case you find his answer too complex to grasp, think of "le" here as "it".

+++++++

Since the French, we know [it], honor the past, age and tradition, [...]